# Webpack using node_modules in vendor chunk without explicitly stating them

Tags: javascript, webpack

So [code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) is the technique of creating different bundles - so app, vendor etc...

I know what I want in my `vendor` bundle but only by convention...

Anything

```
import x from 'name';
import 'name';
```

These need to be in `vendor`, because (i think they are) clearly coming from `node_modules`.

However, I've only seen examples of explicitly stating this.

Is there a way to use convention?

If not, could I build a plugin to do this (this plugin could just go into your dependencies section of `package.json`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is this:

`const pkg = require('./package.json');`

and in your configuration:

```
{
   entry: {
      vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies) // use node_module dependencies
   },
   plugins: [
     new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor"
     })
   ]
}
```

EDIT:
It seems there is a better way to do it. One can use `minChunks` property in the CommonsChunkPlugin plugin. You can pass a function there, as such:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        minChunks: ({ resource }) => {
            return resource && resource.match(/\.js$/) && resource.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
        }
    })
]
```

By doing that, you don't need to rely on package.json list and webpack will consider only dependencies used in the project. neat.

Comment: feels a bit strange to do this, but works - so fine by me :)

Comment: @CallumLinington check out my updated answer, I found another way