# Bundle node-modules separately with Webpack 2

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-2

I'm using webpack 2 to bundle all Javascript (Typescript to be precise, but I don't think that it matters, does it?) of a React/Redux SPA.  My dependencies are in `node_modules`, installed with yarn.

So far I'm just putting everything—dependencies and application code that is—into a single `bundle.js`.  However, since we're frequently changing the application and deploying all changes continuously we'd really like to split all the dependencies into a separate bundle to improve caching and decrease the amount of JS the client needs to fetch.

With the docs about [Code Splitting – Libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/) I managed to configure webpack to split all `node_modules` into a separate JS file, however I noticed that the chunkhash of the dependency bundle changes everytime I change the *application* code, which kind of leads the splitting ad absurdum.

The issue is documented in the [Manifest File](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#manifest-file) section, but that's where I got lost.  I didn't manage to properly split a `manifest` bundle.  In particular the configuration from the previous section which sets up `minChunks` to split out all node-modules is gone in this section, and instead it appears that the dependencies are to be listed as separate entry points.  Now, I have about 20 dependencies or so, and I'd not like to repeat all of them in the webpack configuration.

How do I get webpack to split out all node_modules into a separate bundle that really only changes when I change `node_modules`, without repeating all dependency modules as entry points?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack using node\_modules in vendor chunk without explicitly stating them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350230/webpack-using-node-modules-in-vendor-chunk-without-explicitly-stating-them)