# Third party CSS libraries in Ionic2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic2

How can I use a third party CSS library with Ionic2? I've installed `animate.css` using `npm install animate.css --save`, but I can't find any up-to-date documentation on how to actually add this to the build.

How do I include it?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42353168/1326271

Comment: Since it's css, you could just donwload the `.min.css` file, add it (for instance) in the `assets/css` folder, and add `<link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in your `index.html` file